# How to show partial text column on a page

Tags: html, css, windows-8

When you specify the column-width property in CSS for a div with a bunch of text in it, the actual width seems to be automatically adjusted so that an exact number of columns fit the page. If a column-width of 400px, for instance, is specified and there's actually 1000px of space then instead of showing 2.5 columns of text (with the .5 column overflowing to the right to invite the user to pan), it instead shows an even 2 columns of text.

I found in the dev.windows.com that if you specify values for all of the width properties involved (width, column-width, column-gap, and column-rule-width) then you can achieve this, and that works, but it requires that you determine the width of your containing div and that seems silly since you want that to flow.

Here's my CSS that's not working as I'd like...

```
.csscolumns .columns {
    columns: 400px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    height: 600px;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

Comment: you don't want to expand column but text goes like this `suppose my is something`  if .coloumn width is small then it goes like this `my is some..`

Comment: I don't want to ellipse the text. I want the column to spill off of the page so that all the user has to do is grab the content with a touch gesture and drag left. This should pan the screen to the right and reveal the rest of the story. It already works like this where the user can pan to more text, but I just wanted to show a little of the offscreen text to indicate to the user that they might want to read more.

Comment: Measn like `my name is` read more when you click on read more then it display `my name is something and text goes` like this you want..

Comment: No, that's not it either, Arpit.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried tweaking with 'overflow' in your CSS? Try the following for the selected elements:

```
overflow: hidden;
```

This will hide any 'overflowing' content of the selected elements, behind the parent elements.